# How to perform multiple exists-eliminations that all share a single multivariate universally-quantified hypothesis?

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

The Lean documentation shows the following two examples with just a single variable:

from [Theorem Proving in Lean: Existential Quantifiers](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/quantifiers_and_equality.html#the-existential-quantifier):

```
variables (α : Type) (p q : α → Prop)
example (h : ∃ x, p x ∧ q x) : ∃ x, q x ∧ p x :=
exists.elim h
  (assume w,
    assume hw : p w ∧ q w, -- this is ∀ w, p w ∧ q w
    show ∃ x, q x ∧ p x, from ⟨w, hw.right, hw.left⟩)
```

from [Logic and Proof: Using the Existential Quantifier](https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/first_order_logic_in_lean.html#using-the-existential-quantifier) ***:

```
variables (U : Type) (P : U → Prop) (Q : Prop)
example (h1 : ∃ x, P x) (h2 : ∀ x, P x → Q) : Q :=
exists.elim h1
  (assume (y : U) (h : P y),
    have h3 : P y → Q, from h2 y,
    show Q, from h3 h)
```

In both cases the universal hypothesis (`h2` in the former example, `hw` in the latter) only depends on one variable.

Now suppose that we got (I paraphrase the original problem):

```
variables (U : Type) (P R: U → Prop)(Q : Prop)
example (h1a : ∃ x, P x) (h1b : ∃ x, R x) (h2 : ∀ x y, P x → R y → Q) : Q := sorry
```

In `h2`, imagine that `P` and `R` are like `nat.is_even`, and `Q` is like "x,y form a pair of even numbers".

The interior derivation that `exists.elim` needs, I imagine, would go like:

```
  (assume (y z : U) (ha : P y) (hb : R z),
    have h3 : P y → R z → Q, from h2 y z,
    show Q, from h4 h1a h1b)
```

But I'm not sure how to use it with exists elimination - since essentially two eliminations need to be done at once. `exists.elim h1a (exists.elim h1b (assume ... show Q, from ...))` doesn't work it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
example (h1a : ∃ x, P x) (h1b : ∃ x, R x) (h2 : ∀ x y, P x → R y → Q) : Q :=
exists.elim h1a (exists.elim h1b (assume (x : U) (hRx : R x) (y : U) (hPy : P y), _))
```

There are other ways of doing this. One is to use `let`

```
example (h1a : ∃ x, P x) (h1b : ∃ x, R x) (h2 : ∀ x y, P x → R y → Q) : Q :=
let ⟨x, hPx⟩ := h1a in
let ⟨y, hRy⟩ := h1b in
_
```

Another way is to use the `cases` tactic in tactic mode

```
example (h1a : ∃ x, P x) (h1b : ∃ x, R x) (h2 : ∀ x y, P x → R y → Q) : Q :=
begin
  cases h1a with x hPx,
  cases h1b with y hRy,
end
```